# In checkbox within selectbox how to get the checked value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code i tried to print the selected value from selected box.But its printing only the first value of selected item.I don't know how to get the length of selected value.any one help me for this problem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Dropdown CheckList</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller.css">
        <style>
    table td { vertical-align: top }
    dd { padding-bottom: 15px }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#s10").dropdownchecklist( { forceMultiple: true
    , onComplete: function(selector) {
        var values = "";
        for( i=0; i < selector.options.length; i++ )
        {
            if (selector.options[i].selected && (selector.options[i].value != "")) 
            {
                if ( values != "" ) 
                  values += ";";
                values += selector.options[i].value;            
            }

        }
        alert(values);
        } 
    , onItemClick: function(checkbox, selector)
       {
         var justChecked = checkbox.prop("checked");
         var checkCount = (justChecked) ? 1 : -1;
         for( i = 0; i < selector.options.length; i++ ){
            if (selector.options[i].selected )
              checkCount += 1;
        }


       }
      });
    });
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
      <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="s10">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value='a'>Alice</option>
                    <option value='b'>Bob</option>
                    <option value='c'>Christian</option>
                    <option value='d'>Daniel</option>
                    <option value='e'>Elizabeth</option>
                </select>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

for taking the length of checkbox selected item I did this but i don't know it only giving 1 as alert message

```
onItemClick: function (checkbox, selector) 
                 {
                   $("input:checked").each(function()
                   {        
                         alert($(this).val().length);    
                   });         
                 } });
```

Answer (score 1):

get the selected option with `:selected`:

```
$('#s10 option:selected').val();
```

### What i meant to say is this:  http://jsfiddle.net/T4UDu/

```
$('#s10').change(function(){
    alert($('option:selected',this).val());
});
```

Comment: this printing last selected item first letter

Comment: Why don't you try change event of `#s10` and get the option value?

Comment: what event i want to change

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope it will work

```
<select id="s10" multiple="multiple">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var foo = []; 
        $('#s10:selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
          foo[i] = $(selected).text(); 
        });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: i added this after the dropdownchecklist function is this make any problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkboxId').change(function(){
    alert($('option:selected',this).val());
});
```